# How to add arrays together and make a sum out of the inputted numbers

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sum

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Sum As Integer
    Dim input(9) As Integer

    input(0) = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    input(1) = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    input(2) = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    input(3) = CInt(TextBox4.Text)
    input(4) = CInt(TextBox5.Text)
    input(5) = CInt(TextBox6.Text)
    input(6) = CInt(TextBox7.Text)
    input(7) = CInt(TextBox8.Text)
    input(8) = CInt(TextBox9.Text)
    input(9) = CInt(TextBox10.Text)

    Sum = input(0) + input(1)
    lblTotal.Text = (Sum)
 End Sub 
End Class
```

Hello everyone. I have a dilemma, when i try to add the first two inputs together it gives me back an error and i don't understand why. I simply would like to add all these arrays together but i want the arrays to be numbers i can input. There are ten text boxes on the program itself and a label box where the sum should be displayed. I am trying to understand why i can't even add two inputs, it just errors.  I have to use an array and add them altogether and it has to display.

Comment: What exactly are the errors?

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing? Where are they being thrown from?

Comment: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll this is what comes up guys

Comment: All the textboxes must have values.

Comment: This happens because one or more of your input boxes are empty. Use Int32.TryCast

Comment: ohhh ok let me check something

Comment: THANKS GUYS lol i feel so slow... seriously thanks for the help though i really suck at this coding stuff

Answer (score 1):

To correctly handle user input when you expect numbers you should use the `Int32.TryCast` method that returns false if the input is not a valid number

```
Dim temp as Integer
if Int32.TryCast(TextBox1.Text, temp) then
    input(0) = temp
```

Now you could repeat the same logic for all the other textboxes

Finally you could use the `IEnumerable` extension `Sum` to sum all your values

```
Sum = input.Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lblTotal.Text = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(Function(i) CInt(Val(CType(Controls("TextBox" & i), TextBox).Text))).Sum
End Sub
```